# Converting text to Unicode in javascript

Tags: javascript, unicode

I have the following:

```
function showUnicode()
{
  var text = prompt( 'Enter the wanted text', 'Unicode' ),
      unicode = 0,
      ntext,
      temp,
      i = 0
  ;

  // got the text now transform it in unicode
  for(i; i < text.length; i++)
  {
    unicode += text.charCodeAt(i)

  }

  // now do an alert
  alert( 'Here is the unicode:\n' + unicode + '\nof:\n' + text )

}
```

Thanks for the idea to initialize unicode but now unicode  variable gets the Unicode of the last character, why does it?

Comment: `unicode` is not initialized, so it is `undefined`. In the first iteration, you are basically doing `undefined + someNumber` and [`undefined` is converted to `NaN`](http://es5.github.com/#x9.3).

Comment: charCodeAt returns an integer repsenting the unicode codepoint value. If you add them up as you are, you'll be getting back the equivalent of "1+2+3=6", not "123".

Comment: No need to mask your JavaScript block: <!-- -->

Comment: A good practice - ending each statement with a semicolon.

Comment: well now i initialized unicode to 0 but it shows just the unicode of the last character

Comment: @Andrew: No, it adds all codes to together, as Marc already noted.

Comment: If you want the unicode values altogether as a string, initialize `unicode` to `""`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[JavaScript uses UCS-2 internally.](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-encoding)

This means that supplementary Unicode symbols are exposed as two separate code units (the surrogate halves). For example, `''.length == 2`, even though it’s only one Unicode character.

Because of this, if you want to get the Unicode code point for every character in a string, you’ll need to convert the UCS-2 string into an array of UTF-16 code points (where each surrogate pair forms a single code point). You could use [Punycode.js](http://mths.be/punycode)’s utility functions for this:

```
punycode.ucs2.decode('abc'); // [97, 98, 99]
punycode.ucs2.decode(''); // [119558]
```

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize the `unicode` variable to something, or you're adding the char codes to `undefined`.

Answer (score 1):

NaN = Not a Number

You need to initialize "unicode" as a numeric type:

```
var unicode = 0
```