# Unicode in Rhino

Tags: javascript, unicode, character-encoding, rhino

For some reason Unicode strings don't behave properly in [**Rhino**, Mozilla's JavaScript engine](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Rhino). If I enter Unicode text in the REPL, or manipulate it, it returns back gibberish.

```
js> 'тотальная киборгизация'
B>B0;L=0O :81>@3870F8O
```

ASCII characters work just fine.

```
js> 'reprap for everyone'
reprap for everyone
```

Unix commands work fine too:

```
$ echo 'тотальная киборгизация'
тотальная киборгизация
```

JVM output is fine too, running `class Test { public static void main(String[] args) { System.out.println("тотальная киборгизация"); } }` outputs Cyrillic correctly.

Java and Rhino versions are:

```
$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_09"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea7 2.3.3) (7u9-2.3.3-0ubuntu1~12.10.1)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.2-b09, mixed mode)
$ rhino
Rhino 1.7 release 3 2012 05 18
```

Locales:

```
$ echo $LC_TYPE

$ echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
```

Changing `LC_ALL` to `en_US.UTF-8` doesn't help.

Does this problem have to do with this StackOverflow question, [*Javascript using UCS-2*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9109335/596361)?

**What's the problem, and how can I use proper Unicode in Rhino REPL?**

Comment: I don't see the same problem. I'm using `Rhino 1.7 release 2 2009 03 22` and `java version "1.6.0_26"` `Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_26-b03-384-9M3425)` `Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.1-b02-384, mixed mode)` on Mac OS X 10.5.8.

Comment: Try eliminating Rhino from environment. What happens when you give the Unix command line the command, `echo 'тотальная киборгизация'`, without running Rhino?

Comment: The output you get, after accounting for control characters, is actually UTF-16, not UTF-8. (Given this, the fact that the plain ASCII works is peculiar.) You might try compiling and running this Java to see if the VM's settings are to blame:

`class Test {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
                System.out.println("тотальная киборгизация");
        }
}`

Comment: I just figured this out: The plain ASCII is (probably) just as broken as the Cyrillic and only seems to work because the interspersed nulls between the characters are not displayed.

Comment: Try using Unicorn instead, Rhino should know it better.

Comment: I am not sure which Javascript shell are you using
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Shells

Is it JS shell https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/SpiderMonkey/Introduction_to_the_JavaScript_shell or Rhino shell https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Rhino/Shell

Answer (score 1):

It really should be noted that JavaScript doesn't really handle Unicode properly since it predates UTF16.  (It does use another 16 bit encoding system which is similar, but certainly not the same.)

This  [writeup explains the problem in well and provides libraries and workarounds](http://mathiasbynens.be/notes/javascript-unicode) .